# Boost Libraries: Taboo or useful?

Tags: c++, boost

I've seen some c++ programmers swear by the boost library, and some twitch when I mention boost. However, boost contains a whole slew of useful functions and tools to employ when encountering common c++ related  issues. For the record, is the boost library a good thing, or something to stay away from programming professionally.

Comment: Some parts of the C++ standard were first implemented by boost.

Comment: A lot of professional code uses Boost.

Comment: Yes, it's either a good thing, or should be stayed away from. Seriously, it's up to you to weigh the good and bad points and decide whether it makes sense for your purposes.

Comment: This question is too opinionated for SO. It may be a design question that could be re-worked and asked over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. For the record, I have used boost a ton, much of it is good but I am moving away from it since starting work in C++11/14

Comment: Incidentally, CarCzar's answer provided a sufficient answer as Boost being a resource, rather then a good or bad library.

Comment: @InfinityMachine Incidentally, that doesn't make the question useful, let alone a good match for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boost library is very useful for many people, and provides a lot of functionality.

As to whether it is the right tool for the job is dependent on the project, and the programmer, and is very a subjective question to answer.

There is no correct answer to this question. Boost is neither intrinsically good or bad.